# I installed LinuxMint on my Macbook Pro and now I want OSX back?

Tags: linux, macos, macbook-pro, reinstall

To be really honest, I was really stupid and retarded. I went ahead, one day and completely clean installed LinuxMint on my Macbook Pro. All of sudden, I seem to want OS X back.

I tried making a USB bootable with a Mountain Lion OSX ISO in Ubuntu, but it doesn't boot on my Linux Mint (OS) on Macbook Pro.

What should I do? Please help.

Comment: How old is the Macbook Pro? If it is newer version you may be able to do a Netboot over wireless / ethernet and do recovery installation via internet. Also if you have USB Bootable Mountain Lion (and you are sure it is bootable, not just burning the ISO content into the USB), you should be able to press ALT on boot, and select to boot from USB. But preferably if you have a dual layer DVD drive.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and burn it to a disc and use an optical drive?

Can you simply not boot to USB? Could you select the USB device as the primary boot partition?

Sorry it isn't much help, but there isn't much info to go on, that's why I suggest the optical disc.